# Create random password gives Incompatible types error

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

So far this is my coding. I am making a program to help create a password at random for a user. I am having issues with making the random lettering. I have thought of a way but it is giving me an incompatible error and I tried:

```
chars[] letters= "abecdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
```

here is my code at the moment.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    char letters;
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please choose from the following menu options:");
    System.out.println("[1] Lowercase Letters");
    System.out.println("[2] Lowercase & Uppercase Letters");
    System.out.println("[3] Lowercase, Uppercase, and Numbers");
    System.out.println("[4] Lowercase, Uppercase, Numbers and Punctuation");
    System.out.println("[5] Quit");
    System.out.println ("Enter Selection:");
    int selection = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Password Length (1-14):");
    int length = in.nextInt();
    if (selection == 1)
      letters = "abcdefghisjklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    Stringbuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

Answer (score 0):

toCharArray returns char[] and letters is char only